# Skipping backpropagation for certain element of certain data with stop_recording() in tf.GradientTape()

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient, backpropagation

Suppose I have data of format `(4, 2)`, and my purpose is to predict three 0 or 1.(simple sigmoid problem)
Since I know this data should be handled with CNN, I will use `keras.layers.Conv1D` and so on.

Here's a minimal example.

```
BATCH_SIZE = 2
sample_inputs = keras.Input((4, 2), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE) # shape: (BATCH_SIZE, 4, 2)
cnn_layer = keras.layers.Conv1D(3, kernel_size=2, use_bias=False) # No bias for fewer trainable variables.
cnn_outputs = cnn_layer(sample_inputs) # shape: (BATCH_SIZE, 3, 3)
dense_layer = keras.layers.Dense(1, use_bias=False)
final_outputs = dense_layer(cnn_outputs) # shape: (BATCH_SIZE, 3, 1)

dummy_model = keras.Model(sample_inputs, final_outputs)
```

But my problem is, **I am aware that certain part of `y_true` is wrong!**
Let me illustrate more,

```
train_x = tf.random.normal((BATCH_SIZE*5, 4, 2)) # Let's say we have 10 number of data
train_y = tf.reshape(tf.random.categorical(tf.math.log([[0.5, 0.5]]), 
    num_samples=BATCH_SIZE*5*3*1, dtype=tf.int32), (BATCH_SIZE*5, 3, 1)) # to make values 0 or 1.
```

Say `train_y[2:3, :, :]` is a tensor `shape=(1, 3, 1), dtype=int32, array([[[1], [0], [0]]])`.
 But I'm sure that the first element of this tensor is contaminated. So I don't want my gradients to be backpropagated for this element, but I still want trainable_variables of `dummy_model` to be trained for second and third elements since every data is so valuable.

Question1. Am I logically right for this? I can still calculate `y_pred` using the corresponding one of `train_x` using the model for that contaminated one. And I can also skip the backpropagation of that certain element for the certain data, when it is inevitable right?
(Maybe this can cause some skewness or cherrypicking the data in some sense, I'm aware that)

Question2. Tensorflow Implementation.
After a long research, my strategy is to use `stop_recording()` method of `tf.GradientTape()`.
I will tag(or edit) that contaminated part to an integer `100`, and whenever the loop notice that there is a `100` in `y_batch` using `tf.where(y_batch == 100)`, set the `cond=True`, let the `tf.GradientTape()` do what he did as usual until then, put `tf.UnconnectedGradients.ZERO` instead for that contaminated one, ...

I know this sounds crazy, not even sure whether it would worth. But at least, am I thinking right?

Comment: Well maybe my logic wasn't wrong, since otherwise many people would have criticized..No comment also still helps.